# ResolutionImpossible from pip despite no apparent version conflict

Tags: python, pip

Sometimes pip complains of conflicting dependencies despite there being no actual version conflict, for example in this case even after removing the specific version of `elastic-apm` from constraints.txt entirely (just leaving it in mypackage's setup.py) it still failed as follows:

```
ERROR: Cannot install elastic-apm because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    mypackage 1.2.3 depends on elastic-apm
    The user requested (constraint) elastic-apm

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

This was with pip 22.1.2 & python 3.10 using a command like this (i.e. use a local folder of wheels, not PyPI)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt --no-index --find-links LOCALDIR --no-cache-dir --isolated
```

Why is pip complaining about conflicting dependencies when there are in fact no specific versions or ranges requested at all, never mind conflicting ones?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was that LOCALDIR did not contain a wheel for the current **platform**.

The folder contained this wheel, but not a corresponding Windows wheel (our mistake)

```
elastic_apm-6.10.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

However the pip output is very misleading - the problem was nothing to do with *conflicting* dependencies, it simply couldn't find a package matching the necessary platform - it would be nice if pip told you this.

I've posted on https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11009 which seems similar.